# Can't invoke navigate inside another method

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to navigate to another screen using react-navigation. However with this code I get the error: `undefined is not an object (evaluation 'this.props.navigation')`

When invoking `navigate`directly (see example at the bottom) it works.

What am I doing wrong?

**This does not work:**

```
  _renderRow (rowData) {
    return (
      <View >
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._handlePress} underlayColor='white'>
            <Image
              style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
              source={{uri: 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + rowData.iconName + '.png'}}
            />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }

  _handlePress () {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')
  }
```

**This does work:**

```
  _renderRow (rowData) {
    return (
      <View >
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')} underlayColor='white'>
            <Image
              style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
              source={{uri: 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + rowData.iconName + '.png'}}
            />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: `onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the context. `onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this)}` will do the work.

> You have to be careful about the meaning of `this` in JSX callbacks. In
>   JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to
>   bind `this.handleClick` and pass it to `onClick`, this will be `undefined`
>   when the function is actually called.

Here's the documentation:

[Handling events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)